Adjunction between $\mathrm{Top}$ and $\mathrm{hTop}$
There's a functor $U\colon \mathrm{Top} \rightarrow \mathrm{hTop}$ that is the identity on objects and is the quotient projection (up to homotopy) on hom-sets.
Does this functor have a left (or right) adjoint?

No. If it did, it would have to preserve limits or colimits (depending on the type of adjoint), but $\mathrm{hTop}$ has neither all pullbacks nor all pushouts while $\mathrm{Top}$ does (and every span/cospan in $\mathrm{hTop}$ is in the image of a span/cospan in $\mathrm{Top}$ under $U$).
